# how to dynamic add attributes on Active Model Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I want to decide numbers of attributes to output in my controller.

But I have no idea have to do it?

### controller.rb

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if fields
      # less attributes : only a,c
    elsif xxx
      # default attributes
    else
      # all attributes : a,c,b,d,...
    end
  end
```

### serializer.rb

```
class WeatherLogSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :temperature
  def temperature
    "Celsius: #{object.air_temperature.to_f}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 19):

I would probably do it with a different endpoint for all, but you could also pass in a different url parameter or something of the sort.  Typically, I think you would want the default to be more limited.

Here's how I would suggest doing it:

#### Controller

**Different Endpoint for All**

```
render json: objects, each_serializer: WeatherLogAllSerializer
```

**Allow custom fields**

```
fields = params[:fields] # Csv string of specified fields.

# pass the fields into the scope
if fields.present?
  render json: objects, each_serializer: WeatherLogCustomSerializer, scope: fields
else
  render json: objects, each_serializer: WeatherLogSerializer
end
```

#### Three different serializers: all, default, custom

**All**

```
class WeatherLogAllSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :temperature, :precipitation, :precipitation
  has_many :measurements

  def temperature
    "Celsius: #{object.air_temperature.to_f}"
  end
end
```

**Default**

```
class WeatherLogSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :temperature
  def temperature
    "Celsius: #{object.air_temperature.to_f}"
  end
end
```

**Custom**

```
class WeatherLogCustomSerializer < WeatherLogSerializer

  def attributes
    data = super
    if scope
      scope.split(",").each do |field|
        if field == 'precipitation'
          data[:precipitation] = object.precipitation
        elsif field == 'humidity'
          data[:humidity] = object.humidity
        elsif field == 'measurements'
          data[:measurements] = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(object.measurements)
        end
      end
    end
    data
  end
end
```

Comment: This helped me, but with AMS version 0.10.0, I had to add a parameter to the `attributes` definition. so the only difference is the first two lines, `def attributes(attrs)` and `data = super(attrs)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create different serializers and `respond_with` or `render` with a custom serializer like so:

```
# serialize an array of WeatherLog(s)
render json: objects, each_serializer: WeatherLogSerializer
# serialize a WeatherLog
render json: object, serializer: WeatherLogSimpleSerializer 

# just gimme id and temp
class WeatherLogSimpleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :temperature
  def temperature
    "Celsius: #{object.air_temperature.to_f}"
  end
end

# gimme everything
class WeatherLogSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*WeatherLog.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
end
```